# Do I need a visa to enter Belarus if I have a visa from Russia?

Tags: visas, russia, belarus, cameroonian-citizens

I am a Cameroonian. I have a Russian visa, but I wish to stop at Belarus for a few days on my way to Russia. Will I need a separate Belarusian visa, or will the Russian visa I have permit me to spend a few days in Belarus?

Answer (score 2):

A Russian visa does not exempt you from needing a Belarusian visa.

So yes, you will need it, although it won't be checked at the (open) border.